# get rendered content in an action for ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

every body!

I am new to zend framework, I am working on ajax based tabs in zend framework. On clicking a tab I want am calling an action, I want to get rendered content(content rendered in respective view) to send it as response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
<a href="#" class="tab">Click</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $.get('/controller/ajax', function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    echo 'string';
    exit;
}
```

You just have to add exit; in your action so it doesn't try to render the layout again.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want exactly, but you can  disable rendering of the layout in your action and have only action view script rendered, e.g.

```
public function exampleAction() {

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        $this->view->var = 'some var';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Not an ajax requrests');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Marcin I exactly wanted this! Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. Using exit is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function yourAction() {
        // get response and layout 
        $response                        = $this->getResponse();
        $layout                          = $this->_helper->layout();

        // rendering action's template      
        $this->render( 'template' );   

        // setting content, don't remember to echo $this->Layout()->content in the layout script                           
        $layout->content                 = $response->getBody();

        //  here you can get your rendered content, and do something with it 
        $renderedContent                 = $layout->render( 'layout' );  

        // you have to clean response otherwise will be automaticaly sent
        $response->clearBody();                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, also make sure to add an exit at the end

```
$this->view->assign(array('name' => 'my name', 'msg' => 'my message'));
echo $this->view->render('message/display.phtml');
exit;
```

then in the .phtml file simply call

```
<?php echo $this->msg; ?>
```